# CDI can't set @Singleton into @Provider in @Requestscoped REST service after redeploy on WildFly

Tags: java, rest, ejb, cdi, wildfly

I have AuthenticationFilter and it injects UserController which is annotated with @Singleton. When I deploy my application for the first time - everything is all right, but when I redeploy application and then I try to get something from whichever REST service - often I receive:

```
Can not set app.auth.UserController field
 app.web.rest.auth.AuthenticationFilter.userController to 
app.auth.UserController$Proxy$_$$_Weld$EnterpriseProxy$
```

The problem still occurs even if I kill server and restart it. But after couple of restarts issue finally disappears.

Someone knows what could cause that error?

Comment: Try cleaning target directory before redeployment

Comment: Infact I allways clear target directory before redeployment

Comment: Which Singleton, CDI or EJB?

Comment: This is EJB Singleton

Comment: Did you solve the problem? I have a similar problem

Comment: This should state the used environment

Comment: 1. Which application server ? 2. If you stop the application server, is it really stopped ? Is there an infinite loop or something that might just keep running even after an attemp is made for the application server to shut down ? 

To me, this seems like a problem with stopping the Singleton. Can you show us the code of your Singleton ? Also, is it EJB @Singleton, or java inejct Singleton ?

Answer (score 0):

I had experienced this problem too. With each deployment I would get random fails of injecting (EJB) `@Singleton` and even (CDI) `ApplicationScoped`. 
The problem in my case was that I did **not** have `beans.xml`. Somehow without the `beans.xml` the project did not initialize properly.

When I added (a completely empty) `beans.xml` it was resolved. Hope it helps.